# admin-ajax.php returns 0 even when the post status code is 200 OK

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, admin

I've seen a lot of similar questions and I've incorporated the feedback from the answers but still, the issue is not resolved.

Ajax request is sent on click of a button in js file.

WyrRoute.js

```
clickHandler(e) {
    var ajax_url = my_ajax_object.ajax_url
    var data ={
        'action': 'my_action',
        'question_id': '10183'
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (xhr, x, checkStatus) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(checkStatus.status)
            console.log("success")
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.statusText);
            console.log("failure")
        }
    });
}
}
```

In the receiver.php file I have:

```
<?php 
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
    
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/src/WyrRoute.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script');
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
function my_action(){
   $theQuestion = $_POST['question_id'];
   echo $theQuestion;
   die();
}
```

Comment: Generally, `400`/`0` indicates that no appropriate hook was found for the action. `200`/`0` often means that a hook was found for the action and the action was executed, but that no hooked callback did not terminate the request. But your code looks correct at a glance. You could try a `wp_die()` instead of `die()`, but I'd be surprised if that makes a difference. jQuery is expecting a JSON response body there but potentially receiving a raw response - have you verified that the response is definitively a `200`-code with a `0` body in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: And just for the sake of completeness, you're testing the AJAX request in a browser session with a WordPress user logged in?